# Sonata datepicker not working in other locale

Tags: jquery, datepicker, momentjs, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have a strange issue here: my (French) website is using sonata-admin 2.3, and for the dates in my forms I am trying to use the datepicker:

```
->add('birthDate', 'sonata_type_date_picker')
```

Display is fine, but when I submit a date, i get a "This value is not valid" (in french..) for the date, while with the standard `date` widget everything works fine. I tried setting the locale at `en` instead of `fr` and everything went back to place, the datepicker worked just fine.

This is a pretty nasty bug for me as the `date` widget is not very user-friendly and my client asks for the datepicker...Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to latest version of Sonata fixed this. Moment JS was properly initiated.

Answer (score 0):

please read this documentation

http://obtao.com/blog/2013/04/datetimepicker-field-type-with-symfony-and-jquery/

Comment: Seems to be a lot of work for such a simple thing :(